# combine jQuery click handler with php header on same button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that is now inside a little form:

```
<form name="picSubmit" method="post">
  <button class="btn  btn-block btn-default" id="upload"><?php echo $lrow[10]; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span></button>
</form>
```

then my code on top of the page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/cameraUserScript.js"></script>
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    header('Location: view-subscribe');
}
?>
```

This is some javascript/jQuery ajax code to send the content inside a `<div>` and a picture that i have taken to a php page where i use this content to get some data out of my database and to rename and save that picture into a folder

```
document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
   var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
   var idVal = $('.hiddenId').html();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "incl/camsave.php",
      data: { 
          imgBase64: dataUrl,
          idVal: idVal
       }
    }).done(function(msg) {
    console.log('saved');
    });
```

I added a click event on that submit button ID so that when i click this script has to run. It works in Chrome, but because in Chrome you allways have to click the trust button if you use mediahandling i want to use Mozilla but there it isn't working... Does it has something to do with the combination of the submit button and the click event?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're mixing vanilla JS and jQuery here, but you can likely solve this by changing your code to this -

```
$('#upload').click(function() { // you can use jQuery here too
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    var idVal = $('.hiddenId').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "incl/camsave.php",
        data: { 
            imgBase64: dataUrl,
            idVal: idVal
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log('saved');
    });
});
```

Comment: Well to be honoust this really was a script i have found on the internet. I have just changed it but still not worked for me. I just wanted my PHP to go to another page with `header('Location: view-subscribe');` but for now i have fixed it by going trough my script and adding `window.location = 'view-subscribe';` under `console.log('saved')` is that also a good way to go to another page and not losing my $_SESSION variables? Thx

Comment: Sure, as long as you're starting your session on each page. I'm curious, do you have any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: I am more the backend programmer instead of the front end so javascript and its frameworks is not my best friend but starting to learn it bit by bit now. I just take a look at the console but it is empty of errors so that is good!